# HTML elements ignoring presence of vertically aligned div

Tags: html, css

My div "inner_submit_data" is vertically aligned on my page using the code below. However, if I include further HTML elements below this div they appear at the top of my page, as if they are ignoring the presence of the vertically aligned div. Is there a way for HTML elements appearing after the vertically-aligned div to display below it on my page? I will be adding a lot of dynamic content to my page so I don't think absolute positions is the answer.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="outer_submit_data">
    <div id="inner_submit_data">                     
        <h3 id="instruct">STEP #1: Upload your .csv file</h3>
        <div class="init_buttons" id="upfile1"></div>
        <br>
        <div class="init_buttons" id="upfile2">Continue</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS to make it align vertically:

```
#inner_submit_data {

    /* POSITION */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    width: 40%;
    margin: -10% 0 0 -20%;

    /* DIV DISPLAY PROPERTIES*/
    color: #fdf2e3;
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;

}
```

Comment: That's how `position: absolute` works.  They **are** ignoring it, as intended.

Comment: The absolutely-positioned `#inner_submit_data` DIV is removed from the normal flow of the page.  Your options include putting additional content inside it, make it not be absolute, or to position other DIVs absolutely...

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Thanks for the responses! guess I don't have much choice